# Disable a button until a condition is met in Qt

Tags: qt, qt5

So i'm new into Qt and i'm just testing GUI stuff out, creating windows and widgets, so i want to know if there's a way for me to make a QPushButton disabled until a specific condition is met(until the user inputs their username and password into a QLineEdit widget)...I want that login button to be disabled until the condition is met

[image: loginWindow]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes absolutely you can. You should define a **signal** and **slot** and connect them together. In your slot, enable the login button and where your condition meet trigger the signal by **emit yourSignal()**.

e.g pseudo code:

**class header:**

```
signals:
    void yourSignal();
private slots:
    void onSignalEmitted();
```

**class body:**

```
YourClass::YourClass() {
    connect(this, &YourClass::yourSignal, this, &YourClass::onSignalEmitted);
}

void YourClass::onSignalEmitted() {
    ui->login_button.enable();
}
```

Don't forget to emit your signal when condition meet like this:

```
emit yourSignal();
```

Comment: I can't figure out how to set that when the user has text in both the QLineEdit for username and Password that the custom signal should be emitted

Comment: You should just check the value of password QLineEdit that not be equal to null, on the username QLineEdit on_text_change slot and also check value of username QLineEdit that not be equal to null, on the password QLineEdit on_text_change and when your conditions meet emit created signal (yourSignal)